# Add border in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

In my app, I have designed a view in the interface builder.
This view has a toolbar, with some UIBarButtonItem in.

My buttons can be custom images, or default button like share, add,...
Now with iOS7, buttons don't have anymore borders. So I'd like to add some.
[image]

Here is what i want to do : add borders like the white lines on my screenshot.
What I've tried is to add a UIButton to the toolbar. In my example, I've set my back button size (12x44). I add this button as a IBOutlet property of my view controller, and try to draw a border to it :

```
CALayer *cancelBorder = [CALayer layer];
[cancelBorder setFrame:CGRectMake(12, 0, 1, 44)];
[backBorder setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[backButton.layer addSublayer:cancelBorder];
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Your cancelBorder may be out of the bounds of your backButton. You said your backButton has a width of 12, and your cancelBorder has an x-offset of 12. So the cancelBorder begins outside of the bounds of your backButton and therefor won't be visible(assuming the button has clipToBounds = YES, which i think it hast). Maybe try it with an offset of 8 or something and look if it's visible. For being at the edge it then has to be an offset of 11.

Answer (score 10):

Adding UIBarButtonItem to toolbar programmatically may solve your problem.

First, create custom button with images, borders, etc. As HereTrix said, you can add border to this button.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 30, 30);
button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
/* any other button customization */
```

Then, initialize UIBarButtonItem with that custom button and add this item to your toolbar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.toolBar.items = @[backButton];
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3** : Below is my full implementation for button customization and event handling.

[image: Test UIBarButtonItem]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    button.setTitle("Tester", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .normal)
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let button = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView {
        button.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:80, height:34)
    }
}

func handleButton( sender : UIButton ) {
    // It would be nice is isEnabled worked...
    sender.alpha = sender.alpha == 1.0 ? 0.5 : 1.0
}
```

Hope this helps